# JQuery event.stopPropagation() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html I have a span of class dragHandle embedded within a li.

```
<div class='treeView'>
    <ul class='tree'>
        <li><span class="dragHandle"></span>Item 1
            <ul>
                <li><span class="dragHandle"></span>Item 2 <a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
</ul>
```

I attach event handlers using jQuery as follows:

```
$(".tree li").click(function(event) {
    alert("click");
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".dragHandle").mousedown(function(event) {
    alert("down");
    event.stopPropagation();

});

$(".dragHandle").mouseup(function(event) {
    alert("Up");
    event.stopPropagation();

});
```

When I mousedown and mouse up over the element I get the down and up alerts, however I also get the click alert of the li's event handler too. I thought that this should be prevented from by the call to event.stopPropagation in the mousedown and mouseup handlers. How do I stop the click event being called for mousedown/up events on the dragHandle?

TIA,
Adam

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How do I stop the click event being called for mousedown/up events on the dragHandle?

You capture... and eat... *that* event:

```
$(".dragHandle").click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
```

The key here is that `click`, `mousedown`, and `mouseup` are distinct events. Although you might think of a `click` as being a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`, in reality you might have `click` events triggered by user actions that don't even involve the mouse, as well as combinations of `mousedown` and `mouseup` that don't result in any `click` events at all.

Comment: Cheers for that, I was considering a click event as a mousedown and mouse up.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a simple wrapper-"class", that keeps track of mouse-down and up events:

```
(function () {
   var DragDropHandler = {
      isDrag: false,

      mouseDownHandler: function (event) {
        alert("down");
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.isDrag = true;
      },

      mouseUpHandler: function (event) {
        alert("Up");
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.isDrag = false;
      },

      clickHandler: function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         // Check if we've already received a mouseDown-event. If we have,
         // disregard the click event since we want drag-functionality
         if(this.isDrag) { return; }
         alert("click");
      }
   };

   $(".tree li").click(function(event) {
      DragDropHandler.clickHandler.call(DragDropHandler, event);
   });
   $(".dragHandle").mousedown(function(event) {
      DragDropHandler.mouseDownHandler.call(DragDropHandler, event);
   });
   $(".dragHandle").mouseup(function(event) {
      DragDropHandler.mouseUpHandler.call(DragDropHandler, event);
   });
})();
```

This creates a closure and delegates the event handling to the DragDropHandler-object. Note that I've used function.call (the first parameter is the context) to ensure that *this* refers to the DragDropHandler-object inside its methods. Since we have created an anonymous function that can not be reached from global space, I think it's acceptable to use the DragDropHandler reference inside the wrapper event handlers.