# event.stopPropagation(); on Smartphones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to show a mobile navigation. On my computer it works fine but in mobile browsers the `event.stopPropagation();` doesn't work

```
$('.show').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#mnav').slideToggle(500);
});

$(document).click( function(){
    $('#mnav').hide();
});
```

Comment: does it work if you simply use `return false;` after your `slideTogle()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Test it:

```
$('.show').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#mnav').slideToggle(500);
    alert('okshow');
});

$(document).click( function(){
    $('#mnav').hide();
    alert('okdocument');
});
```

Check this topic: [JQuery event.stopPropagation() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184955/jquery-event-stoppropagation-not-working)

I'm not sure, but I think you need something like this to work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mnav').hide();

    $('.show').click( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#mnav').slideToggle(500);
    });

});
```

Comment: @user2416687 What you have described is what I would expect to happen. What are you expecting?

Comment: I need a code that does exactly that on Smartphones what the code above does on my computer.

Comment: In CSS i did this: #mnav { display: none; } I think it's the same as $('#mnav').hide();