# Clicking inside element and dragging mouse outside it

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, onclick

I'm sure somebody out there already had such problem, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer.

```js
window.onload = function (e) {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
    foo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('foo');
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      alert('body');
    });
};
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
```

Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogachinchaladze/n5a1t4cc/) and 
I will describe my problem step-by-step:

1) Click the red div
2) Do not release mouse button and drag it outside

As you can see the body click function fires. That's what I want to disable. I want to detect if the user clicks inside the div and if then he/she drags outside it, nothing must happen!

Comment: `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` could solve this issue in particular.

Comment: i think you are playing with the wrong events ! try with mousedown and mouseup. And to play with drag this is usefull : drag, dragend, dragleave, dragenter, dragover, dragstart ... from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: This is interesting too - it still fires the `click` on `body` even when the `mouseup` is over another element that is not bubbling up events : http://jsfiddle.net/y0q8rw0g/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Firefox is the only browser that's not firing a click when the cursor has moved away from the original element. On webkit related browsers there is no trace of the original `mousedown` but all event data is based on the fact as if a complete click was fired on `body`. So there's no way to make a distinction based on the click itself. There are likely a few workarounds but here's one - checking if any click originated from a `mousedown` on the element :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var foo = document.getElementById('foo'), fromfoo,
origin  = document.getElementById('origin');

foo.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    fromfoo = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {

    fromfoo = false;
});

foo.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    if (fromfoo) origin.innerHTML = 'foo';
});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {

    if (fromfoo) origin.innerHTML = 'different';
    else origin.innerHTML = 'body';
});
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#origin {
  float: right;
  margin: 50px 100px;
}

#foo {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="origin"></div>
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
```

Quite a workaround but part of it is because of making it reverse compatible with Mozilla.

Edit - very strange this is what the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says :

> For example, if the user clicks the mouse on the object but moves the mouse pointer away from the object before releasing, no onclick event occurs.

But that doesn't seem to be the case at all.

---

Update - also found this report after much searching :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=484655

So it seems to be at least buggy behaviour or a misinterpretation of the W3 spec. Apparently a known issue with IE and one that showed up recently with Chrome. This question from 2013 about IE only looks related as well. Someone posted a small plugin that could be of interest still :

[Internet Explorer leaks click event after adding an overlay in a jQuery mousedown handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215427/3168107)

Comment: Sorry for 'ignoring', indeed your answer is very helpful and I also had the idea like this, but the solution is not an perfect. I'll look forward to the ideal one and if nobody appears, will choose your answer as a solution !

Comment: Thanks for replying - and sorry about the impatience. I've looked into this extensively, logging the events themselves as well and comparing them in every detail. The phantom click on `body` seems to be identical to clicking on it directly. Unfortunately clicks themselves cannot be prevented, just their default action and the fact if they will be bubbling up or not. So I don't think there's a way around using these different events. Seems a bit overcomplicated to match it with all browsers but looks unavoidable. It's a very interesting question you posted that turns up empty results on Google.

Comment: Yeap, I also think nobody will find a solution better, but let's wait one more day and then I'll check your answer ! Thanks for help again mate!

Comment: If there's anyone offering a better solution, I'd be glad to see it and will definitely upvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

> Prevents other listeners of the same event from being called.

Source MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

```js
window.onload = function (e) {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
    foo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('foo');
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      alert('body');
    });
};
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem :( did you test it?

Comment: Just updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gogachinchaladze/n5a1t4cc/ but works as early